# XSLT transformation to transform XML to a customized XML to map to a table schema in DB

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am trying to transform the following XML1 to XML2. But couldn't do it and couldn't find similar examples. Cans someone help. This is my first try to transform XML using XSLT.

XML1 (Current XML):

```
<Data>

 <Set label="NY">        
 <value>42.000000000000000</value>
 <value>339.000000000000000</value>
 </Set>

 <Set label="NJ">        
 <value>0.000000000000000</value>
 <value>14.000000000000000</value>
 </Set>

 <Set label="TN">        
 <value>0.000000000000000</value>
 <value>14.000000000000000</value>
 </Set>

</Data>
```

XML 2 (Desired XML):

```
<Data>

 <Set1 label="NY">
 <datapoint1>42.000000000000000</datapoint1>
 </Set1>

 <Set1 label="NJ">        
 <datapoint1>0.000000000000000</datapoint1>
 </Set1>

 <Set1 label="TN">        
 <datapoint1>0.000000000000000</datapoint1>
 </Set1>

 <Set2 label="NY">
 <datapoint2>339.000000000000000</datapoint2>
 </Set2>

 <Set2 label="NJ">        
 <datapoint2>14.000000000000000</datapoint2>
 </Set2>

 <Set2 label="TN">        
 <datapoint2>14.000000000000000</datapoint2>
 </Set2>

</Data>
```

Comment: *This is my first try to transform XML using XSLT* ...and where is this trial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the XSLT V1.0. Let me know if it works for you.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="var1_initial" select="."/>
        <Data>
            <xsl:for-each select="Data/Set">
                <xsl:variable name="var2_current" select="."/>
                <Set1>
                    <xsl:attribute name="label">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@label"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:for-each select="value">
                        <xsl:variable name="var3_current" select="."/>
                        <datapoint1>
                            <xsl:value-of select="number(.)"/>
                        </datapoint1>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </Set1>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="Data/Set">
                <xsl:variable name="var4_current" select="."/>
                <Set2>
                    <xsl:attribute name="label">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@label"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:for-each select="value">
                        <xsl:variable name="var5_current" select="."/>
                        <datapoint2>
                            <xsl:value-of select="number(.)"/>
                        </datapoint2>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </Set2>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Data>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another XSLT 1.0 option...

**XML Input**

```
<Data>

    <Set label="NY">        
        <value>42.000000000000000</value>
        <value>339.000000000000000</value>
    </Set>

    <Set label="NJ">        
        <value>0.000000000000000</value>
        <value>14.000000000000000</value>
    </Set>

    <Set label="TN">        
        <value>0.000000000000000</value>
        <value>14.000000000000000</value>
    </Set>

</Data>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|Set/value[1]"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Set/value[2]"/>
    </xsl:copy>    
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="value">
    <xsl:variable name="pos">
      <xsl:number/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:element name="Set{$pos}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="../@label"/>
      <datapoint><xsl:value-of select="."/></datapoint>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<Data>
   <Set1 label="NY">
      <datapoint>42.000000000000000</datapoint>
   </Set1>
   <Set1 label="NJ">
      <datapoint>0.000000000000000</datapoint>
   </Set1>
   <Set1 label="TN">
      <datapoint>0.000000000000000</datapoint>
   </Set1>
   <Set2 label="NY">
      <datapoint>339.000000000000000</datapoint>
   </Set2>
   <Set2 label="NJ">
      <datapoint>14.000000000000000</datapoint>
   </Set2>
   <Set2 label="TN">
      <datapoint>14.000000000000000</datapoint>
   </Set2>
</Data>
```

---

Here's one more option if the number of `value` elements is unknown or can vary...

**XML Input** (modified to have varied number of `value` elements)

```
<Data>

    <Set label="NY">        
        <value>42.000000000000000</value>
        <value>339.000000000000000</value>
    </Set>

    <Set label="NJ">        
        <value>0.000000000000000</value>
        <value>14.000000000000000</value>
        <value>77.000000000000000</value>
    </Set>

    <Set label="TN">        
        <value>0.000000000000000</value>
        <value>14.000000000000000</value>
        <value>77.000000000000000</value>
        <value>18.000000000000000</value>
    </Set>

</Data>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!--Create a key of sets based on the number of values.-->
  <xsl:key name="sets" match="Set" use="count(value)"/>

  <!--Determine the max number of values in a set. (Using key above.)-->
  <xsl:variable name="maxValues">
    <xsl:for-each select="/Data/Set[count(.|key('sets',count(value))[1])=1]">
      <xsl:sort select="count(value)" order="descending"/>
      <xsl:if test="position()=1">
        <xsl:value-of select="count(value)+1"/>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>    
  </xsl:variable>

  <!--Identity transform. Copies attributes and nodes unchanged.-->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/Data">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:call-template name="processSets">
        <xsl:with-param name="currentIteration" select="1"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="processSets">
    <xsl:param name="currentIteration"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Set/value[position()=$currentIteration]"/>
    <xsl:if test="$maxValues > $currentIteration + 1">
      <xsl:call-template name="processSets">
        <xsl:with-param name="currentIteration" select="$currentIteration + 1"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="value">
    <xsl:variable name="pos">
      <xsl:number/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:element name="Set{$pos}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="../@label"/>
      <datapoint><xsl:value-of select="."/></datapoint>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<Data>
   <Set1 label="NY">
      <datapoint>42.000000000000000</datapoint>
   </Set1>
   <Set1 label="NJ">
      <datapoint>0.000000000000000</datapoint>
   </Set1>
   <Set1 label="TN">
      <datapoint>0.000000000000000</datapoint>
   </Set1>
   <Set2 label="NY">
      <datapoint>339.000000000000000</datapoint>
   </Set2>
   <Set2 label="NJ">
      <datapoint>14.000000000000000</datapoint>
   </Set2>
   <Set2 label="TN">
      <datapoint>14.000000000000000</datapoint>
   </Set2>
   <Set3 label="NJ">
      <datapoint>77.000000000000000</datapoint>
   </Set3>
   <Set3 label="TN">
      <datapoint>77.000000000000000</datapoint>
   </Set3>
   <Set4 label="TN">
      <datapoint>18.000000000000000</datapoint>
   </Set4>
</Data>
```